# How can I verify clickable hyperlink given in a table using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify that links given in table column is clickable or not.

I tried using list but I am not getting any idea what should I try next to solve this task.

[image: image1]

'''

Btech Consulting Pty Ltd
               CTR002
               2018
               
                  19/02/2019
               
               
                  
                     Transmitted

'''

I need to click on the status which is "Transmitted" in this row. I need to check if link is clickable or not

Comment: Please provide DOM or site.

Comment: I can't share the code . Also i dont understand why i am unable to share the html of that table

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to fetch all the links in the table, then click each of them and verify that the URL changes (by asserting on the returned value of driver.url)